# How to do this in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a dps script that does this

```
create vdisk file="C:\Image.vhd" maximum=10000 type=expandable
attach vdisk
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs quick
rescan
assign letter=I
```

How can I do this in PS 5.1?

Comment: I would just run the shell file from powershell.  Put commands into a file and make file executable.  The run file from you shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to install Hyper-V and the associated PowerShell Module and then you could create the disk:

```
New-VHD -Path "C:\Image.vhd" -Dynamic -SizeBytes 10485760000
```

Mount, or attach, the disk then initialize it (assuming there is only one extra disk, if there are more than one disk you'd need to get the number using `get-disk`).

```
Mount-VHD -Path "C:\Image.vhd"
Initialize-Disk -Number 1 -PartitionStyle GPT
```

Then create the partition, set the drive letter and quickly format with NTFS

```
New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -DriveLetter I | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -Quick
```

Comment: I'm creating it inside a VM. The vm itself got one VHDX and it got size of 60GB. Can I set this new VHD to more than 60?

Comment: You can set the size of the VHD to any size up to 2TB, if you change to using VHDX you can have any size up to 64TB

Comment: When I make the VHD more than the free space on the VHDX, I get blue screen saying `VHD boot host not enough space`. I don't know if it matters but I'm flipping the boot drive from C (the VHDX total 60GB) to D drive (new VHD). VHD image is on C drive.